# APT: Public Key is missing? How to fix?

Tags: debian, apt, xtrabackup

I updated my sources.list with

```
deb http://repo.percona.com/apt squeeze main
deb-src http://repo.percona.com/apt squeeze main
```

And called

```
 gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv-keys 1C4CBDCDCD2EFD2A
```

The Result was, that it seemed to import something, so the key was found on this sever!?

Nevertheless now I get the error:

> GPG error: http://repo.percona.com squeeze Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1C4CBDCDCD2EFD2A

1. How can I disable/ignore the keychecking in apt in general?
2. What is the adviced way to fix the problem itself. Is there some way to search the key somewhere elese? How would I do that?

Comment: Could someone please DELETE the question? I missed the steps to import the key into apt!!! Please do NOT answer the question...

Comment: How can I delete my posting?

Comment: Just leave it there, maybe someone else has the same problem and will find their solution here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add the key to apt using `apt-key`:

```
gpg -a --output /tmp/pub.asc --export 1C4CBDCDCD2EFD2A
sudo apt-key add /tmp/pub.asc && rm /tmp/pub.asc
```

cf. http://blog.edseek.com/archives/2007/03/17/apt-key-gpg-key-import-on-ubuntu-and-debian/

Answer (score 5):

The key is also directly available from the Percona website.
Import it as following:

```
wget -O - http://www.percona.com/redir/downloads/RPM-GPG-KEY-percona | gpg --import
gpg --armor --export 1C4CBDCDCD2EFD2A | apt-key add -
```

---

Edit: Percona is going to change their SSH key before the end of this year.
See instructions on their website http://www.percona.com/ssh-key-rotation/instructions

Comment: that worked for me today on a Ubuntu 12.04