# Debian key expired - how to update?

Tags: linux, debian

I am new on Linux distribution and I have a problem I did not manage to fix. I tried to update my Debian computer with `apt-get update`. But at the end, I obtained the following error:

```
.W: Erreur de GPG : http://repo.mongodb.org jessie/mongodb-org/3.4 Release : Les signatures suivantes ne sont pas valables : KEYEXPIRED 1515625755
```

I don't know how to fix it. The computer date is correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [APT: Public Key is missing? How to fix?](https://serverfault.com/questions/356986/apt-public-key-is-missing-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me with mongo 3.4

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6 && sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, you need to "install" the key again

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver <mongodb repo keyserver> --recv-keys <last 8 digits of key>
```

---

Some googling resulted in this

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
```

taken from [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-31459?focusedCommentId=1703071&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-1703071)

Comment: Thank you for your rapid response. 
I wrote :
apt-key adv --keyserver <mongodb repo keyserver> --recv-keys A15703C6

I tried it and I get the following things :
bash: mongodb: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type ...

Comment: I found [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-31459?focusedCommentId=1703071&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-1703071) on an external site. This works for me, I'll update my answer.

Comment: When I wrote :    apt-key list | grep "expirée", I obtained  : pub   4096R/F6D61D45 2015-05-27 [expirée : 2017-05-26]

So I tried the 2 above commands with the key digits "F6D61D45"...

Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.G3nMFB1M1e --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/chris-lea-redis-server.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/d [...]

Is is normal ?

Comment: Did you try `apt-get update` after that ?

Comment: I did and the "W: Erreur de GPG : http://repo.mongodb.org jessie ..." dit not appear anymore ! However, when I checked the validity of the keys (apt-key list | grep "expirée"), I obtained :

pub   4096R/F6D61D45 2015-05-27 [expirée : 2017-05-26]

So the key is still expired right ?

Comment: @balou, yes, the old key is expired, this added the new key